# Is there any practical semantic difference between the comma operator and the semicolon?

Tags: c, operators, comma-operator

Here's what I understand so far:

1. The comma operator allows for brevity of code, e.g. `int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0` as opposed to `int x = 0; int y = 0; int z = 0;`.  In this case it's sort of like syntactic sugar for a semicolon.
2. The comma operator acts as a sequence point.  So in the code `f(), g();`, the function `f()` is guaranteed to execute and produce all of its side effects before `g()`.  But the same is true if you use the code `f(); g();`.
3. The comma operator is an operator, whereas the semicolon is simply a program token that takes no part in the evaluation of expressions.  Since the comma operator has such low precedence, it differs very little from the semicolon in this regard.

So, I'm wondering what is the semantic difference between these two constructs in practice?  Is there any situation where using a comma would produce different results from using a semicolon?

Comment: When declaring or defining variables, the comma is *not* the command *operator*, it's just a separator between the different declarations.

Comment: `int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0` is __not__ the comma operator

Comment: And note that the semantics of the comma *operator* is different in C and C++, so please edit your question to use only the language tag you're actually wondering about.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying that.  So the comma operator is basically just a stand-in for a semicolon when separating function calls then?

Comment: This is simply too broad. and yes, there are cases where they are vastly different altogether.

Comment: Comma will return the lvalue of the last operand. You can write ugly code like `(b += 3, a) = 5;` if you want.

Comment: Related:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator  (I think the wiki is easier to understand for this case than the cppreference one)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited the tags and removed #c++.  This question mainly concerns C, but I thought the semantics were the same in both C and C++ (isn't C++ a superset of C?)

Comment: Also it lets you write ugly stuff like (see example):  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator

Comment: @ShobladeX read the tag for c++;  you'll note that it STARTED as a superset; but has diverged

Comment: C++ is a completely different and separate language from C. While some syntax and ***some*** semantics are shared, C++ have things like operator overloading, and you can overload the comma operator to mean something completely different.

Comment: @liliscent Okay, that makes sense.  Obviously a semicolon wouldn't work there.

Comment: @liliscent, in C++, yes, but not for C. Here, the result of the comma operator is an rvalue so the example that you are giving is invalid.

Comment: *The comma operator allows for brevity of code*  That's not necessarily a good thing.  "Brevity of code" is all too often a way to hide bugs in subtle ways.  You don't get bonus points for stuffing as much code into as few lines as possible.  What you do get is unmaintainable code, and that's **BAD**.

Comment: The only use for this operator is pretty much to write icky one-liner function-like macros, that must return a value as if it was a function call. Needless to say, such macros should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cases where comma is used as a token, there are other cases where the comma is a [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Quoting wikipedia,

> The use of the comma token as an operator is distinct from its use in function calls and definitions, variable declarations, enum declarations, and similar constructs, where it acts as a separator.

One example to clarify, (borrowed directly from chapter §6.5.17, `C11` standard)

You can have a function call made like

```
  f(a, (t=3, t+2), c);
```

here, the comma in `(t=3, t+2)` is a comma operator, this is valid and accepted.

However, you cannot write

```
  f(a, (t=3; t+2), c);
```

this is a syntactic error.

Comment: The r-value result of `(t=3, t+2)` is the value of `t+2`. Is there a sequence point at the comma operator? Then the result is 5; otherwise it would be undefined?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  ... and I quote, `The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value`

Comment: ...and the left operand can be any expression, including another comma-operator. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 4):

In case of

```
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0 ;
```

`,` is not a *comma operator* but they are comma separator.
Semicolon is part of statement and declarations.

```
int i = 0;  // declaration
i = i + 5;  // statement
```

On the other hand, comma operator is part of expressions. That said semicolon can't be used where an expression is expected. For example

```
if(++i, i < 10) { /*...*/ }  // A semicolon can't be used.
```

Answer (score 1):

One situation where it does make a difference is this:

```
while(foo(), bar()) {
    ...
}
```

I don't know if there's any real practical usage for this, but it does compile with a comma, but not with a semicolon.

Comment: ..because a semi-colon is a statement terminator, which cannot be in expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator has been fairly well discussed in other answers. Remains the semi-colon.

The semi-colon (`;`) is a *statement terminator*, meaning that it terminates the syntax of any statement. It also means that an expression, when followed by a semi-colon, is turned into a statement:

```
foo();                // a statement
bar();                // a statement
3+5;                  // a statement
(t=3, t+2);           // a statement
while(foo(), bar());  // a statement

while(foo(), bar()) {
    ;                 // empty statement
}
```

The semi-colon also terminates declarations.